scripting.executeScript: Calling chrome.tabs.sendMessage right after Causes dreaded "Receiving end does not exist."
Question
Is there a way to get around timing issues when injecting a content script via chrome.scripting.executeScript() and sending the tab a message?
Issue
In this code, I am injecting a content script into a tab and then sending the tab a message. Unfortunately, this will throw the dreaded Receiving end does not exist. issue unless I add a setTimeout() call, which I absolutely don't want to do (very bug prone to do that). Is there some way to make this work without the timeout?
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(async (onClickData, tab) => {
  await chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    target: { tabId: tab!.id! },
    files: [schedulerScript],
  });

  
  await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 100)); //<-- "Receiving end does not exist." throw if this isn't here

  await chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab!.id!, {
    type: "setActiveEditableElement",
  });
  await handleMenuItemClick(onClickData, tab);
});

Here's the contents of the script I'm writing into the tab:
import { handleMessage } from "./messageHandlers";

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(handleMessage);


Attempts I've Made
I've tried playing around with the content script sending a message back to the service worker to say it's ready, but this is pretty convoluted, service worker -> content script -> content script sends message back to service worker -> service work then tells it to do something. This is pretty hard to maintain.
Interesting. In this question it looks like it's suggested to supply a function that returns a promise. That forces the executeScript() call to wait for the promise to settle. Worth looking into.
Any ideas are appreciated. Have you run into timing issues where a script's handlers aren't ready?

I can't reproduce the problem though, the plain JS code works for me without setTimeout, so apparently your content.js doesn't add the listener immediately, which may be caused by the way it's bundled.

Interesting! I'm using crxjs and running in development mode locally. I did a static build and could replicate the issue.

Can you upload the extension so I can try it myself? The only other explanation is a bug in Chrome which I couldn't replicate.

I ended up going the retry route if the first call fails. Not sure if I can upload the extension :-\

You can test it yourself. 1) Add console.log(await .........executeScript(.......)), 2) edit the final js file for the content script in build or dist folder and add console.log(1) after addListener() and console.log(2); 2; at the end of the file. Check the console for the background script, which should print [{result: 2}], and the content script, which should print 1 and 2.
